# onDownloadProgress in axios call isn't working

Tags: javascript, axios

The onDownloadProgress event is never being triggered in an axios.get.  The download works as expected but I wanted to be able to update the user on the progress of the download.

The following code works as far a downloading the zip file but onDownloadProgress is never called:

```
axios({
    url: "/rest/downloadInfo",
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'blob', 
    },{
        onDownloadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
            let percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
            console.log(progressEvent.lengthComputable)
            console.log(percentCompleted);
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        const href = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = href;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'downloadFile.zip'); //or any other extension
        
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();

        // clean up "a" element & remove ObjectURL
        document.body.removeChild(link);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(href);
        
});
```

Comment: when so you want to call the on download load progress  ?

Comment: the code block missing a `"` at `url`

Comment: Sorry about the missing " at the url.  In the actual code it isn't missing.  I added the missing " in the post.

Comment: I expected the on download progress to start when the downloading of the data begins.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `axios()` directly, you only pass in **one** config value with all the properties. So your call should be this

```
axios({
    url: "/rest/downloadInfo",
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'blob', 
    onDownloadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
            let percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
            console.log(progressEvent.lengthComputable)
            console.log(percentCompleted);
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        const href = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = href;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'downloadFile.zip'); //or any other extension
        
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();

        // clean up "a" element & remove ObjectURL
        document.body.removeChild(link);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(href);
        
});
```

The only time the configuration is the second option is if you're using one of the helper methods, e.g. `axios.get(url, config);`